# JavaScript .match() returns null even though it has values

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on a online game and I'm writing something to handle the packets. The code:

```
inf1.forEach(function(value,index){
    m = value.match(/\[[^\[\]]*\]/g);
    inf2[index] = new Array();
    m.forEach(function(val,ind){
        inf2[index][ind] = val;
    });
});
```

If I run something like

```
alert(m[0]);
```

under

```
m = value.match(/\[[^\[\]]*\]/g);
```

It works fine. But the forEach doesn't work.
It will return an error saying: m is null.
I tried it with the jQuery $.each too, but it didn't work either.

Example value of "value"

> [%31][%48%75%72%65%6E%73%6F%68%6E%7C%53%65%78%79]

I can't find where the problem is.

Comment: Can you please show us the sample of `value`?

Comment: `[%31][%48%75%72%65%6E%73%6F%68%6E%7C%53%65%78%79]`

Comment: may be the `value` is not matching the pattern.

Comment: Thanks thefourtheye. The problem was, that one value didnt match the pattern. And because it was going through an entire list of these values, I didn't see at which value the error was occuring